# Best way to manage dynamic content without databases

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am designing a web application which will be doing three things:

1) store some data

2) make user available to view these data

3) from time to time add/remove/change some data

Looks pretty simple, but I would like to minimase usage of server resources by avoiding MySQL and PHP. My main goal is to deliver HTML file for user - posts1.html (posts2.html, posts3.html... (where 1,2,3 are numbers of pages of data)).

Normally, I would create posts.php file, which would send query to database, but my data are changing only three-five times a day, so it would be a huge waste.

Instead, I thought about caching these data, what would spare a lot of server resources, but in this situation there would be some of PHP code involved.

My another idea is to create script that would be creating all HTML files after every change in database and then replace the old ones with them. But what if someone requests page that is replacing right now? It may cause errors, user can get the uncompleted file etc.

However, there is one solution - I could store created HTML files in two directories (A and B) and using .htaccess do something like this (pseudocode):

```
if ( (HOURS)%2 == 0 )
   /postsX.html -> /A/postsX.html
else
   /postsX.html -> /B/postsX.html
```

It would give me enough time to upgrade all files.

I would love to hear what do you think about it and what would you do?

Comment: I would go with caching. Just build a normal, simple app. Build an admin so that you can easily edit your pages. Then use caching to make it fast and minimize access to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to use a full blown MySQL server, use [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php). It's part of PHP and very lightweight. Then add caching where appropriate. Your other approaches sound like a waste of time to me. Too much effort for too little gain. SQLite and caching is tried and tested.

Besides, you should not worry about waste of resources unless you are running short on them. Your application doesnt sound like it needs scaling at this point. So build the simplest thing that will work.

If you have to have that static pages approach, then put all those files into a symlinked folder. Create a script that generates the static pages into a new folder (either via cron or manual trigger) and then changes the symlink from the old folder to the new folder. This way you don't have to worry about people hitting your site while its generating content.

Comment: My website generates really huge amount of pageviews. It is really important for me.

Comment: define huge please. Have you profiled your application? Do you know if you are memory, i/o or cpu bound? did you run ab or siege against it? are you running apc or memcached?

Comment: 10000 hits a day are about 7 per minute. that's easy to handle for any webserver and database (unless your queries are extremely heavy)

Comment: 100.000 pageviews, 20-30 queries per page --> ~2.500.000 queries a day. Let's say I want to make the most of my server and my provider is easly-provoked

Comment: still easy to handle with proper caching and maybe some query tuning.

Answer (score 0):

you should use SQLite with ADODB or any other supported database and implement caching. See the ADODB compatibility list http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#drivers. The caching feature is really powerful, ADODB is very famous and well documented.